# Loading data from json file in select2

Tags: json, jquery-select2

I have a json file tags.json with values in format ["samsung","cell phone","galaxy s4"].

HTML:

```
<input type='hidden' id='inputSearch_Tags'>
```

JS:

```
 $("#inputSearch_Tags").select2({
            multiple:true,
            tokenSeparators: [","],
            ajax: {
                url: "js/tags.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term, page) {
                  return {
                    q: term
                  };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                  return { results: data };
                }
            }
});
```

Select2 is not loading data from the json file.

Comment: Maybe data should be as.. data:[{id:0,text:'enhancement'},{id:1,text:'bug'},{id:2,text:'duplicate'},{id:3,text:'invalid'},{id:4,text:'wontfix'}]